# Cannot display menu on click using context menu prime ng angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, babylonjs

I am using angular 15 with prime ng 15.
I am trying to display 3 dots (...) in the table to show the action menu (edit and view) on click of dots.
I am using p-contextMenu but the context menu is opening on the right click and I am unable to open it on any other click. I want to open it on the button click and not on the right click.
Here is my code for HTML:

```
<td id="action">
            <button
              #contextMenuTarget
              pButton
              icon="pi pi-ellipsis-v"
              (click)="openContextMenu($event, rowData)"
            ></button>
            <p-contextMenu
              [model]="actionsMenu"
              [target]="contextMenuTarget"
              appendTo="body"
            ></p-contextMenu>
          </td>
```

Code for ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.actionsMenu = [
      {
        label: 'Edit',
        icon: 'pi pi-pencil',
        command: (event) => this.editTicket(event.item.data.id),
      },
      {
        label: 'View',
        icon: 'pi pi-eye',
        command: (event) => this.ViewTicket(event.item.data.id),
      },
    ];
  }

  openContextMenu(event: Event, rowData: any) {
    this.contextMenuTarget = event.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
    this.actionsMenu.forEach((item: any) => (item['data'] = rowData));
  }
```

Please suggest solutions.

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `p-menu` and set the menu popup property to true like the following:

```
<p-menu #menu [model]="items" [popup]="true"></p-menu>
<button pButton type="button" (click)="menu.toggle($event)" icon="pi pi-bars" label="Show"></button>
```

The context menu was created to open a menu overlay when the user performs a right-click action on an element.